# How to serialize property of type Object with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, xmlserializer

I have a property:

```
public object Tag
```

but it can contain finite number of types, unfortunately without base type (except object type). But when I serialize the object with this property, it doesn't get serialized. Is there a way to instruct XmlSerializer with possible types?

Comment: I'd expect you could implement ISerializable and control the serialization of the object depending on the type of Tag by casting it to it's serializable type.  However I don't know how you would deserialize the object later.  It's possibly not a good idea to serialize things of type object.

Comment: @Adrian `XmlSerializer` doesn't care about `ISerializable`; however, I do agree that frankly this scenario is best simply avoided

Comment: @Marc XmlSerializer doesn't care about ISerialiable however it does care about IXmlSerializable and will call the read and write methods on an object that implements it.

Comment: @DarenFox Cheers, I'd forgotten that it's IXmlSerializable for the XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't recommend this, but yes, you can use `[XmlElement]` etc to tell it about multiple candidate types for a member:

```
public class Test
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Test));
        var obj = new Test {Value = "abc"};
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, obj);
        obj = new Test { Value = 123 };
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, obj);
        obj = new Test { Value = 456.7F };
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, obj);
    }

    [XmlElement("a", Type = typeof(int))]
    [XmlElement("b", Type = typeof(string))]
    [XmlElement("c", Type = typeof(float))]
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

The important bits of the output (ignoring all the `xmlns` / `<?xml>` etc) are:

```
<Test>
  <b>abc</b>
</Test>

<Test>
  <a>123</a>
</Test>

<Test>
  <c>456.7</c>
</Test>
```

Comment: This only works if you use different names or namespaces for the elements though (a,b,c in this example). In my case, I needed the element name to always be the same, so I posted an answer that seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I did it implementing the `IXmlSerializable` interface, writing the object type as an element attribute.

```
  public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
  {
     reader.MoveToContent();

     Boolean isEmptyElement = reader.IsEmptyElement; 
     reader.ReadStartElement();
     if (!isEmptyElement)
     {

        // ...here comes all other properties deserialization

        object tag;
        if (ReadXmlObjectProperty(reader, "Tag", out tag))
        {
           Tag = tag;
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();
     }
  }

  public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
  {

     // ...here comes all other properties serialization

     WriteXmlObjectProperty(writer, "Tag", Tag);
  }

  public static bool ReadXmlObjectProperty(XmlReader reader, 
                                           string name,
                                           out object value)
  {
     value = null;

     // Moves to the element
     while (!reader.IsStartElement(name))
     {
        return false;
     }
     // Get the serialized type
     string typeName = reader.GetAttribute("Type");

     Boolean isEmptyElement = reader.IsEmptyElement; 
     reader.ReadStartElement();
     if (!isEmptyElement)
     {
        Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);

        if (type != null)
        {
           // Deserialize it
           XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
           value = serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        else
        {
           // Type not found within this namespace: get the raw string!
           string xmlTypeName = typeName.Substring(typeName.LastIndexOf('.')+1);
           value = reader.ReadElementString(xmlTypeName);
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();
     }

     return true;
  }
  public static void WriteXmlObjectProperty(XmlWriter writer, 
                                            string name,
                                            object value)
  {
     if (value != null)
     {
        Type valueType = value.GetType();
        writer.WriteStartElement(name);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Type", valueType.FullName);
        writer.WriteRaw(ToXmlString(value, valueType));
        writer.WriteFullEndElement();
     }
  }

  public static string ToXmlString(object item, Type type) 
  {
     XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
     settings.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
     settings.Indent = true;
     settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
     settings.NamespaceHandling = NamespaceHandling.OmitDuplicates;

     using(StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter()) 
     using(XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings)) 
     {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(type);
        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, item, new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty }));
        return textWriter.ToString();
     }
  }
```

Note: in the code I use no namespace and ASCII encoding, those are non mandatory choices.

HTH,
Cabbi

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `[XmlInclude(typeof(YourType))]` on the **class** that contains the object property. So in the case of the OP, it would look like this

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(PossibleClassOne))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(PossibleClassTwo))]
public class MyClass
{
   public object Tag { get; set; }
}
```

This way, you can keep your element name `<Tag>` in all cases

Comment: This does not seem to work with simple types like bool/int/float/string