# Serialize property of type object

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

I have a serializable class which contains some properties, including a variable of type object. I want my class to be able to contain different (of course serializable) objects. The problem is, that I get an exception during serialization:

```
Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically
```

I created a small sample for this issue:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SerializeableTestClass testClass = new SerializeableTestClass();

        testClass.Params = new ExtendedParams();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlSerializer xmlf = new XmlSerializer(testClass.GetType());
        xmlf.Serialize(ms, testClass);
        ms.Capacity = (int)ms.Length;
        ms.Close();
        byte[] array =  ms.GetBuffer();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class SerializeableTestClass
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Params")]
    public object Params;
}

[Serializable]
public class ParamsBase
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SomeValue")]
    public Int32 SomeValue;
}

[Serializable]
public class ExtendedParams : ParamsBase
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SomeNewValue")]
    public Int32 SomeNewValue;
}
```

Is there a possibility to serialize and deserialize this class without specifying the concrete type of "Params" ???

Best regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to serialize property of type Object with XmlSerializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497310/how-to-serialize-property-of-type-object-with-xmlserializer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it acceptable to include all the possible types on the class that is serialized? (That is what the message means, that no type info is included for `ExtendedParams`).

You can include it in the `XmlSerializeritself`, or include it on the main class:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ParamsBase))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ExtendedParams))]
public class SerializeableTestClass
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Params")]    
    public object Params;
}
```

But to dynamically serialize if you don't know all the types:

```
//static: XmlSerializer xmlf = new XmlSerializer(testClass.GetType(),new Type[]{typeof(ExtendedParams)});

//dynamic:
Type[] extratypes = testClass.Params == null ? null : new Type[] { testClass.Params.GetType() };
XmlSerializer xmlf = new XmlSerializer(testClass.GetType(), extratypes );
```

Comment: @Emu Added dynamic serialialization option, for the case you describe that the parameter type is not known beforehand

Answer (score 1):

modify your code , when you initialize the XmlSerializer

```
 XmlSerializer xmlf = new XmlSerializer(testClass.GetType(),new Type [] {typeof(ExtendedParams)});
```

this will let the XmlSerializer know about the other types in the class

Comment: Yes this solution works. So there is no way to serialize the SerializeableTestClass without specifying the type of the Params object?

Comment: I think you can use this line for more generalization      XmlSerializer xmlf = new XmlSerializer(testClass.GetType(),new Type [] {testClass.Params.GetType()});

Answer (score 0):

As the exception message suggests, you need to specify the derived type so that it can be recognized:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ExtendedParams))]
public class SerializeableTestClass
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Params")]
    public object Params;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't want the SerializeableTestClass to know about the type of the Params, because that means that I have to modify the source of my SerializeableTestClass every time a new object type will be added