# xml serialize crash when calling serialize mehod

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-deserialization

After lot of debugging I came to know exact cause of the crash. Firstly

Test 1:

I am loading an XML file from drive deserializing it against a MOTORCLASS and using the MOTORCLASS properties, later serializing back again to XML It works fine.

Test 2:

I have a Datatable and all its rows are mapped to the MOTORCLASS properties and now when serializing to XML a crash occurs..

When looking into MOTORCLASS property

```
    `public object APPOINTMENT
    {
        get
        {
            return this.aPPOINTMENTField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.aPPOINTMENTField = value;
        }
    }`
```

On run time the TEST 1 sets APPOINTMENT as **Xmlnode** whereas 
TEST 2 assign APPOINTMENT  as **Datetime**.

I think if I convert Datetime to Xmlnode than it should solve the problem. But not sure how to achieve it. I have tried 
`[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("APPOINTMENT")]`.

But it still Datetime. Can anyone shed some light here.

TEST 1:

[image]
TEST 2:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the type of value itself that happens to be assigned to the property; It's the `XmlSerializer` that needs to know beforehand what type it can expect.

If `APPOINTMENT` *should* always be a `DateTime`, just change the property type to `DateTime`. Besides fixing the xml serialization problem, this will also prevent bugs and improve your application's performance.

If `APPOINTMENT` can be different things, you can supply type candidates to the serializer:

```
[XmlElement("AppointmentAsDateTime", Type = typeof(DateTime))]
[XmlElement("AppointmentAsOtherType", Type = typeof(OtherType))]
public object APPOINTMENT { get; set; }
```

This allows the serializer to be able to deal with situations where `APPOINTMENT` is a `DateTime` or an `OtherType`.

(Credit to that solution goes to Marc Gravell: [How to serialize property of type Object with XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497310/how-to-serialize-property-of-type-object-with-xmlserializer))