# How to make property value serialize nested into element named after property?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I want to be able to serialize

```cs
class A {
   Base Prop{ get; set; }
}
class B:Base { [XmlText] string Foo {get;set; }
class C:Base { [XmlText] string Bar {get;set; }
```

to

```xml
<A>
  <Prop>
    <B>blah</B>
  </Prop>
</A>
```

However, the default behavior gives me

```
<A>
  <Prop xsi:type="B">blah</Prop>
</A>
```

So basically, I want to discriminate type of the property's value by nesting an element instead of using xsi:type.

Is it possible to do with XML serialization attributes, or do I have to resort to IXmlSerializable?

Comment: If you're willing to just have `<A><B>blah</B></A>` without the intermediate `<Prop>` element, you can add `[XmlElement(typeof(A))] [XmlElement(typeof(B))]` to `Prop` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9497501/3744182) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36804496/3744182).

Comment: @dbc , nah, that would damage readability.